# Input and Output of all funds in the same block?

Tags: transactions, timestamp

Hope, someone can clarify this problem to me.

Please have a look at the btc address: 1CRTSXJXa3LsaHwjTA5yTbqbyi6QituztX
There have been 2 transactions so far. 1 input and 1 output.
BUT: According to the blocktime and height, these transactions happend at the same time. How is this possible, as I can't transfer funds, that I haven't received in advance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two transactions associated with the address: `1CRTSXJXa3LsaHwjTA5yTbqbyi6QituztX`

Tx 1: [e53cfb481ea8c2e2ff2827c7148393fbd617d7fc545c4a1a475221839344ca48](https://btc.bitaps.com/e53cfb481ea8c2e2ff2827c7148393fbd617d7fc545c4a1a475221839344ca48/1CRTSXJXa3LsaHwjTA5yTbqbyi6QituztX)

Fee: 0.00009072BTC
Fee rate: 3.02 satoshi/vByte

Tx 2: [9fa21b4ed7b242f0ddf1962c8f942109ae8f48ec5b03fff8e00a03e116c6bd44](https://btc.bitaps.com/9fa21b4ed7b242f0ddf1962c8f942109ae8f48ec5b03fff8e00a03e116c6bd44/1CRTSXJXa3LsaHwjTA5yTbqbyi6QituztX)

Fee: 0.00002724BTC
Fee rate: 12.16 satoshi/vByte

Both were included in block [598408](https://btc.bitaps.com/598408)

This is possible and you can always spend unconfirmed UTXO. Child tx will use higher fee rate, this is dependent on parent tx so both are included in same block. If the fee rate for both transactions combined is higher than most of the transactions in mempool, miners will prioritize such transactions.

Child pays for parent: [How would you create child pay for parent in bitcoind-cli](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/99677/how-would-you-create-child-pay-for-parent-in-bitcoind-cli/)

Comment: Thx for your reply and excellent explanation. I appriciate it.